# Validate 8 digit GTIN barcode

Tags: python

So I need to write a program which gives the user two options: A) Validate GTIN code or B) Find 8 digit of a GTIN code from a 7 GTIN code. To find out the 8th digit of a GTIN code from a 7 digit GTIN code each digit in the 7 GTIN code must be multiplied in order like this

[image]

Then subtract the sum from 50 to get the 8th digit. 
I am however struggling to make the code, whenever I press B or b instead of displaying the results I want it displays "for i in gtin:
NameError: name 'gtin' is not defined" 
Here is the code

```
question = input("Would you like to A)Validate your code or B) Find the 8th digit?")
if question in "Aa":
    barcode = input("Please enter your 8 digit number")
counter = 0
sum = 0
for i in barcode:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter % 2 != 0:
        sum = sum + int(i) * 3
    else:
        sum = sum + int(i) * 1  
if sum % 10 == 0:
    print("Valid GTIN")
else:
    print("Invalid GTIN")

if question in "Bb":
    gtin = input("Enter your 7 digit number")
for i in gtin:
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter % 2 != 0:
        sum = sum + int(i) * 3
    else:
        sum = sum + int(i) * 1

print(sum)
lastdigit = 50 - sum
print("8th digit ", lastdigit)

print("Full 7 digit number ", gtin)
print("Full 8 digit number ", str(gtin+str(lastdigit)) )
```

Also when I press A or a it gives me the results I want but also displays the message "for i in gtin:
NameError: name 'gtin' is not defined"

[image]

I do not want this message to be displayed

Comment: "Doesn't work" is a bit general. What happens exactly?

Comment: You need to share the results that you get so we can help determine what is happening.  Also, based on the formatting in your question, you may need to read up on python indentation rules.

Comment: Your code isn't valid: input `1111111` yields `8th digit  47`... 47 is not a digit. `111111147` is likewise "valid" according to your code. Your validator is missing a step for GTIN validation. You need to look over your spec again. Also, most confusingly, your `a/b` options are the opposite of what the prompt states.

Comment: @TheAwsome [gs1 disagrees](http://www.gs1.org/check-digit-calculator) and gives `11111115`

Comment: Why dont you handle all input at beginning of the code? That would make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I actually want to delete this post, something is indeed wrong with the code itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Generating and Validating barcodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42611781/python-generating-and-validating-barcodes)

Answer (score 0):

It breaks because it doesn't know what barcode is because it hasn't been set to anything because it is blocked waiting for user input for an option they didn't choose.

try this:

```
question = input("Hellp, would you like to A) Validate you barcode or B)Find out the 8th digit number?")
if question in "Bb":
    # do B stuff
elif question in "Aa":
    # do A stuff
```